# How to convert PPT to jpeg using php COM class

Tags: php, com, jpeg, powerpoint

I am trying to convert ppt slides to an image(s) using the php COM class

When I try to do this I receive the following error:

`Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007<br/><b>Description:</b> PowerPoint could not open the file`

The code I am using is below:

```
    <html>
      <head>
          <title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> <?= $ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application"); 

          $ppApp->Visible = True; $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); 

          $ppName = "MySlides.ppt"; $FileName = "MyPP"; $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName)); 

          $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,17); $ppApp->Quit; $ppApp = null;

          ?> PowerPoint Created to Folder 
          <b><?=$FileName?></b> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<?=
 $ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");
 $ppApp->Visible = True;

 $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])));

 $ppName = "MySlides.ppt";
 $FileName = "MyPP";
 
 $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));

 $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,17);
 $ppApp->Quit;
 $ppApp = null;
?>
PowerPoint Created to Folder <b><?=$FileName?></b>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please can you include a question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to convert ppt slides  to image using php COM class

Comment: I have added your comments into your question so you can have a look about how to post a good question but you will not get any help unless you have some detail.. Please take the time to read how to post a question here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible to loop over all slides and use Slide.Export?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slide-export-method-powerpoint